# iOS App runs in simulator and devices ,But hangs in Xcode instruments- Memory allocations

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

iOS App runs in simulator and devices ,But hangs in Xcode instruments- Memory allocations.
Actually, application in titanium framework.

Comment: delete your derived data and try it